# #ifdef is causing a conflict, even though i used #endif

Tags: c

That's what i am doing, but its giving me : 
" Error: conflicting types for value_t "

I am not sure why it's not working, can anyone help?

This is inside a header file that i am using for two programs one of them is being run with -DFRACT.

While the other with -DINT, and i am not running -DINT and -DFRACT together, so why is it causing a conflict?

gcc -DFRACT -o program1 program1.c

That's how i am running program1 ..

For program2: 
 gcc -DINT -o program2 program2.c

I also checked all my other header files for Duplicates and i found none
thank you!

```
#ifdef INT   
typedef int value_t;   
typedef double Key_t;
#endif


#ifdef FRACT     
typedef  Fraction value_t;  
typedef double Key_t;
#endif
```

Comment: Aside: `typedef double Key_t;` is common to both, so consider not duplicating the code

Comment: Unable to reproduce the error from your code. You must have `#define INT` and `#define FRACT` together in some way. You should check all your header files, not just this one. What other headers does this file include? Have they defined these macros together in any way? Or, did you forget to `#undef` something?

Comment: " i am not running -DINT and -DFRACT together". Do you just think that or have you proven it? Verify by looking directly at the actual preprocessed output. If using `gcc`, the option is `-E`. As it is, we can't really help as there is not enough info in your question for us to see the problem.

Comment: i checked all of them, there is no other defines for INT and FRACT

Comment: gcc -DFRACT -o program1 program1.c thats how i am running program1 and for program2 gcc -DINT -o program2 program2.c

Comment: try adding this to your code (3 separate lines): `#if defined(INT) && defined(FRACT)` `#error "both INT and FRACT defined"` `#endif`

Comment: Show the contents of program1.c and program2.c as well (and which one is giving the message?)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but to help you with technical terms: You don't **run** programs by calling the compiler on its source, you **translate** (or compile, sic!) them. You run your programs by the command lines `program1` and `program2`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to do something along the lines of this:

```
#if defined (INT) && defined (FRACT)
  #error both defined
#elif defined (INT)
  typedef int value_t;   
#elif defined (FRACT)
  typedef Fraction value_t;  
#else
  #error neither defined
#endif
```